# tkinter: use single button with multiple frames and functions

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I have a list called 'pages' which consists of multiple frames x1 to x5. I want to be able to navigate between them by using tkraise(). The x1 frame will only have a next button in the centre that raises x2, x5 will only have a previous button in the centre that will raise x4. Frames x2 to x4 will have next and previous buttons that will raise the next and previous frame accordingly, and the buttons’ positions will have to be adjusted so that they’re beside each other.

Is it possible to achieve all that with a for loop using just one previous and next button? I was able to get a previous/next button in frames x2 to x4 using my for loop, but I’m not sure what to put for the command so that they can raise the according previous/next frame (I put ? next to lambda). May someone please help.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

box = Frame(root)
box.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
box.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
box.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

x1 = Frame(box, bg="gainsboro")
x1.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")

x2 = Frame(box, bg="red")
x2.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")

x3 = Frame(box, bg="blue")
x3.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")

x4 = Frame(box, bg="green")
x4.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")

x5 = Frame(box, bg="snow")
x5.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")

frames = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]

next_button = Button(frames[0], text="Next", command=lambda: frames[1].tkraise())
next_button.pack()

previous_button = Button(frames[-1], text="Previous", command=lambda: frames[-2].tkraise())
previous_button.pack()

for x in frames[1:4]:
    next_button_2 = Button(x, text="Next", command=lambda: ?)
    next_button_2.pack(side=RIGHT)

    previous_button_2 = Button(x, text="Previous", command=lambda: ?)
    previous_button_2.pack(side=LEFT)

x1.tkraise()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over `frames[1:4]` won't work very well here, as it leaves you with no easy way to get the next/previous frame.  Try iterating over indices instead:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    nb = Button(frames[i], text="Next", command=frames[i+1].tkraise)
    nb.pack(side=RIGHT)
    pb = Button(frames[i], text="Previous", command=frames[i-1].tkraise)
    pb.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Note: instead of lambdas, I've just set the `tkraise` method itself as the command.  This is possible only because it takes no parameters.  Otherwise, you'd run into the usual problem with lambdas in a loop: any local variables they access would always be seen with the values they had during the LAST iteration of the loop.  If you wanted to use lambdas, you'd have to capture the value of `i` as a parameter:  `lambda i=i: frames[i+1].tkraise()` for example.

Actually, it would be fairly simple to handle the end cases in the same loop, thus saving yourself a bit of code duplication:

```
for i in range(len(frames)):
    if i != len(frames) - 1:
        nb = Button(frames[i], text="Next", command=frames[i+1].tkraise)
        nb.pack(side=RIGHT)
    if i != 0:
        pb = Button(frames[i], text="Previous", command=frames[i-1].tkraise)
        pb.pack(side=LEFT)
```